# rate limiting algorithm suggestions for the given scenario

Tags: java, algorithm, memcached, rate-limiting

What is the best mechanism to implement the below rate limiting use-cases. General algorithms like Token Bucket can be used but I want the implementation to be in the context of memcached. Appreciate the help on this.

- allow only 100 calls from customer ABC in a day.
- allow only 50  api calls for customer ABC in an hour.
- allow only 5 api calls for customer ABC for any userid in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when when this limit is reached?  You can prevent service or redirect to a come-back-tomorrow page, but that's pretty ugly.

You can slow down the rate their requests are processed but this is more useful for rates of several per second. e.g. customer ABC is limited to 100 per second or per minute.  For the very low rates you are talking about, the client would time out and think the server is dead.

Comment: The numbers in the post are just examples. Also, I'd like to prevent the service.

Comment: In that cause, increase the counters and if they reach the limit, return a page which says the user should come back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly each API request comes with a userID and customer. Each customer can have multiple user ids. You want to rate limit both at customer and userID level.

You will need to use multiple keys ABC_day, ABC_hour, ABC_userID1_hour, ABC_userID2_hour etc to count the number of times these activities have occurred.  The problem with this approach is when to reset these counters. Since memcached only supports increment operator on numerical values we need to encode this information in the key itself. We can use ABC_2012_02_28 as the key for day rate limit. In your code just create they key using current date and increment it.  When the day changes your code will look for ABC_2012_02_29 which doesn't exist and gives you a chance to create a new key.

Alternative is cacheismo. It is a cache like memcached and supports memcached protocol and it provides "in cache" scripting. Instead of creating so many keys, you can implement your own "ratelimiting" object which will do all this bookkeeping for you.
See http://chakpak.blogspot.in/2011/09/rate-limitingquota-with-cacheismo.html for sample implementation of rate limiting. You can get it from here. https://github.com/iamrohit/cacheismo.